# How to create passenger.conf during passenger installation

Tags: passenger

When installing passenger on a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 machine using [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/xenial/install_passenger.html), the installation fails because there is no file `/etc/nginx/passenger.conf`

Should I create this file manually or is this a bug in the install script?

Comment: That does sound like a bug, were there any unusual messages during installation? And is this reproducible?

Comment: There were no errors during installation. How should I reproduce, do I have to uninstall everything first?

Comment: If that's convenient. You could also use a fresh clean server.

Comment: I uninstalled (using http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/p/passenger/uninstall/index.html) and reinstalled. Everything is ok now! (?) This time there was a line "include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;" in nginx.conf. The first time I installed, there was no such line.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, it sounds like something did go wrong the first time, but if we can't reproduce it then I'll just be content that your setup is working.

Answer (score 2):

I found workaround for that issue. You need to login as root (sudo does not work for some reason). That purge all existing installations of nginx&passenger and their configs (make sure that you made a BACKUP of any nginx configs you made):

```
apt-get purge nginx* passenger
apt-get autoremove
rm -rf /etc/nginx
```

Then, when you repeat install steps from documentation - it will work. It's some sudo related issue.